# how to save dat.gui parameter to backend, i am using django and three.js and dat.gui

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

I am using django as backend and model.form for data saving. i am using dat.gui with three.js scene. my question is how do i save dat.gui parameter to django. (how to get dat.gui parameter to django form)

Answer (score 1):

The dat.gui API has a [`.getSaveObject()`](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/API.md#GUI+getSaveObject) call. Call that,  do `JSON.stringify()` on the result value and send the string to your backend (e.g. using `fetch()`).

You can then use `gui = new GUI({load: saveObject});` when instantiating your dat.gui to load the state.

Comment: Can you share any small examples.